# connecting via plain ftp from vsftpd

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I have a vps running ubuntu 14.04 on digitalocean. I set up
vsftpd and am able to connect via sftpd from winscp or filezilla.
Transfer files without a problem and so on. But when I decide
to connect via regular ftp with the same exact credentials and
port 21, I get an error saying login details are incorrect.

```
/etc/vsftpd.conf has these settings
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Does anyone have any solution/idea?

Comment: Are you connecting to port 22 when using WinSCP/FileZilla, or port 21?  Could it be that you are currently connecting using _SFTP_, not _FTP_?

Comment: I'm using port 21.